# How do these modern multi-lens/multi-sensor smartphones work?

Tags: lens, metadata, smartphone

My last smartphone just had one front lens, so I could understand.
My current phone has three front lenses (and three sensors, too, I guess), so I was a bit surprised, that I had zero control over the lens in the camera app.

Even when viewing the EXIF data with `exiftool`, there was very little detail on which lens had been actually used to take the shot.

So I wondered how do these modern multi-lens cameras work: Is there a single camera/sensor in use, or are the results of multiple sensors being mixed for the overall result ("multi-framing")? (Actually when matching the human eye, mixing a telephoto lens for the center with some wide angle might make sense).

My smartphone is a OPPO Find X5 Lite.

Comment: I've removed questions 2 and 3 here as they were essentially product requests which are off-topic here. The main question is a good one and interesting.

Comment: Which phone are you asking about. With an iPhone you can select the camera in the app by selecting 1X or 2X on my 10S for instance. My wife’s iPhone 12 has 0.5X and 1X options.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Well #2 might be an Android question, but an answer might still be interesting, just as #3 would IMHO.

Comment: @Eric There is no "Android" tag yet, and PhilipKendall removed the EXIF data that showed the manufacturer and model.

Comment: Merging the pictures would be great. They could get closer to HDR merging on the fly picture from lenses with different exposure. They could also remove easily dust specs since every sensor sees different spots. But I suspect they do none of this because the processor on the phone does not have enough processing power.

Comment: *how do these modern multi-lens cameras work?* you should share what brand/model you are actually asking this question about. They simply don't *all* work the same way.

Comment: @MrUpsidown (and others) I repeat myself: If someone hadn't edited the question and had removed the EXIF data I had provided, you would not have to ask. One line was: "Camera Model Name : OPPO Find X5 Lite"

Comment: You are free to edit your question and add this information back in. I agree, it wasn't a good idea to remove that (I submitted an edit now). DXOmark provides *some* clue about this model: https://www.dxomark.com/oppo-find-x5-lite-camera-test/

Comment: From what I read so far is (most likely) that there is *no common* method using multiple sensors and lenses, and (as was obvious from the EXIF data provided) EXIF data does not help what's being used in some/many/all(?) cases.

Comment: @FluidCode it is pretty difficult to merge images taken at different focal lengths - there will be a different field of view, and depth of field to contend with. While not specifically to deal with dust noise, but more noise that results from very low light, phones like the Google Pixel use Night Sight which takes many consecutive images and overlays them to create effectively a long exposure but uses computational algorithms to optimise the result.

Comment: @martyvis Do you mean that the purpose of many cameras is just to cover different focal lengths and all the smartphones with more than one camera mount cameras with different focal length? It seems quite limited considering all the improvements you could have with multiple cameras.